# Using a single codebase for multiple web sites

Tags: asp.net, version-control

There are existing questions that pertain to this subject, but I feel my case may be slightly different(correct me if i'm wrong).

I have two web sites that are almost identical as far as graphics go. They will need only to have a different logo. Additionally I have set up the database so that products can be flagged to show up on either or, or both web sites. Is it possible to set up IIS to point the second web site to the first web site and then have my code determine which domain the request is coming from?

For instance, web site 1 will have domain `www.myfirstwebsite.com` and the second web site will have a domain like `www.mysecondwebsite.com`.

If I did go this route I'm guessing I would check in the master page code behinds `Page_Load` event for the domain and then when I want to display products on my front end I can reference against the variable in the master page. This way seems the easiest and less complex for me, but is it a bad idea?

Comment: Is it possible to have a separate database for each site? It would probably make your code a lot cleaner. If you have a separate database, then using logic similar to @citronas you could change the connection string to a different database, and your queries would all work the same. However, if they are mingled in the same database, you will need to keep track of 1) what site you're on 2) all your queries must implement logic to only load the appropriate content. This could be done by making sure you add a parameter ID to all queries or some such, but you do have to touch all queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. The magic word is called `Themes`.
Check this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx?ppud=4

Assign two bindings in the IIS, for `www.myfirstwebsite.com` and `www.mysecondwebsite.com`
You need to include some like this

```
 if(this.Request.Url.StartsWith("www.myfirstwebsite.com")
 {
  this.Theme = "firstwebsite";
 }
 else if(this.Request.Url.StartsWith("www.mysecondwebsite.com")
 {
  this.Theme = "secondwebsit";
 }
```

Comment: this might be overkill if it's just a logo change. It might be easier just to have some code in your master page that changes the logo based on the startswith..

Comment: The logo will change, and some products will only display on one or the other.